# Populate column in a dataframe A based on a range given by two other columns in dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515826/populate-column-in-data-frame-based-on-a-range-found-in-another-dataframe): We are not comparing indices

Let me create two DataFrames for your understanding to illustrate what I want.

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1], [1], [2], [2], [3], [4], \
              [4], [5], [6], [6], [7], [8]], columns = ['Number'])

B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 'CAT'], [4, 6, 'DOG'], [7, 7, 'COW']], \
columns = ['start', 'end', 'animal'])
```

are my two dataframes.

```
print(A)
```

yields

```
    Number
0        1
1        1
2        2
3        2
4        3
5        4
6        4
7        5
8        6
9        6
10       7
11       8
```

and

```
print(B)
```

yields:

```
   start  end animal
0      1    3    CAT
1      4    6    DOG
2      7    7    COW
```

So my `start` and `end` range is given in `B`, based on this range, I want to populate `A` with a new column which hold the value of the `animal` in `B` if the `Number` column in `A` falls in the `start` and `end` range inclusive of `B`.

So I want to modify the SAME DataFrame `A` to look like;

```
    Number Animal
0        1    CAT
1        1    CAT
2        2    CAT
3        2    CAT
4        3    CAT
5        4    DOG
6        4    DOG
7        5    DOG
8        6    DOG
9        6    DOG
10       7    COW 
11       8    None
```

Keep in mind that this is just a demo dataframe for your to construct, in reality, the two dataframes contain MANY ROWS and MANY columns, so this must be as efficient as possible!

---

This is what I tried:

I created a dictionary to store the range mapping..

```
rangeMapping = {}
for index, row in B.iterrows():
    rangeMapping[row[2]] = (row[0], row[1])
```

printing this `print(rangeMapping)`

`{'CAT': (1, 3), 'COW': (7, 7), 'DOG': (4, 6)}`

```
A['Animal'] = '' #Creating any empty column with empty string
```

and then, I traverse through each row in `A`, and as I do, I then iterate through the `key, (start, end)` pair from the `rangeMapping` dictionary, see if my row value in `A` falls greater than or equal to `start` and less than or equal to `end`, and then add the `key` which is the animal name to the string

```
for index, row in A.iterrows():

    for key, value in rangeMapping.items():

        if((row[0] >= value[0]) and (row[0] <= value[1])):

            row[1] = row[1] + key
            print(row[1])
            break
```

The updated or rather, the column that needs to be updated by the values is being printed

```
CAT
CAT
CAT
CAT
CAT
DOG
DOG
DOG
DOG
DOG
COW
```

but my DataFrame `A` is still having the empty string in the second column..

```
    Number Animal
0        1       
1        1       
2        2       
3        2       
4        3       
5        4       
6        4       
7        5       
8        6       
9        6       
10       7      
11       8
```

I know that first, my code is not the right way to even update row by row, and even if it was there is no way this is efficient, since in reality, my DataFrame `A` has 8000 rows, and DataFrame `B` containing the `start` and `end` columns has 500 rows.. Is there a  more efficient way to do this? (It is that this point I really envy those people who know `pandas` and `subsetting`, `iloc`, `loc`, `index resetting` related commands really well)

EDIT: Included another value in DataFrame in `A` which does not have a range in `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can doing with `IntervalIndex` and `.loc`

```
B.index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(B['start'],B['end'],closed='both')

A['Yourcolumn']=B.animal.loc[A.Number].values


A
Out[1577]: 
    Number Yourcolumn
0        1        CAT
1        1        CAT
2        2        CAT
3        2        CAT
4        3        CAT
..     ...        ...
6        4        DOG
7        5        DOG
8        6        DOG
9        6        DOG
10       7        COW
[11 rows x 2 columns]
```

Update

```
B.index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(B['start'],B['end'],closed='both')
s=sum([list(range(x,y+1)) for x,y in zip(B.start,B.end)],[])
v=A.Number[A.Number.isin(s)]
A.loc[v.index,'Yourcolumns']=B.loc[v].animal.values

A
Out[1652]: 
    Number Yourcolumns
0        1         CAT
1        1         CAT
2        2         CAT
3        2         CAT
4        3         CAT
..     ...         ...
7        5         DOG
8        6         DOG
9        6         DOG
10       7         COW
11       8         NaN
[12 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Really.. It was this simple all along?

Comment: no it's not working.. Looks like there are some rows in `A` that don't have the `(start, end)` index matching from `B`.. Any way to solve this problem? 

edit: YES. I noticed that the code runs into an issue of there is NO (`start, end`) index matching, like if the DataFrame `A` has a row with value `8`

Comment: @Abhishek you should exclude them when do .loc , then concat it back

Comment: I don't know how to now compare to see if there is a value in 'A' that doesn't fall in the range in 'B' and then remove those

Comment: @Abhishek then you sample data can not reproduce your problem , please fix it

Comment: @I've edited the problem and added a new sample where there is an extra value 8