# Python : Update Values of a Column based on Date Range from another Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

There are 2 dataframes `df` and `events` which look like below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Place':['university','residential','hospital','university','residential','hospital'],
                   'Date':['2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-02','2017-01-02'],
                   'Event':['None','None','None','None','None','None']
                })
events = pd.DataFrame({'Place':['university','residential','hospital'], 'Start_Date':['2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01'],
                                      'End_Date':['2017-02-26','2017-01-02','2017-01-02'],
                                       'Event':['UniHolidays','PublicHoliday','PublicHoliday']})

#Convert to datetime
events.Start_Date = pd.to_datetime(events.Start_Date.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
events.End_Date = pd.to_datetime(events.End_Date.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

df has 1 record for every date in 2017 for each place

```
df:
    Date         Place            Event
    2017-01-01   university        None
    2017-01-01   residential       None
    2017-01-01   hospital          None
    2017-01-02   university        None
    2017-01-02   residential       None
    2017-01-02   hospital          None
```

The second dataframe contains events for these places but with a date range

```
events:

Place     Start_Date     End_Date   Event
a      2017-01-01      2017-02-26   UniHoliday
b      2017-01-01      2017-01-02   PublicHoliday
c      2017-01-01      2017-01-02   PublicHoliday
```

The task is to update `df` using `events` such that

if `df.Place` = `events.Place` and `df.Date` is in range (`events.Start_Date, events.End_Date`) then `df.Event` should be updated with the corresponding `event.Event`

The expected output is:

```
Date        Place                Event
    2017-01-01  university       UniHoliday
    2017-01-01  residential      PublicHoliday
    2017-01-01  hospital         PublicHoliday
    2017-01-02  university       UniHoliday
    2017-01-02  residential      PublicHoliday
    2017-01-02  hospital         PublicHoliday
```

There are no overlapping events, every place has a unique record of events

so far I have been thinking along the lines of:
[Populate column in data frame based on a range found in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515826/populate-column-in-data-frame-based-on-a-range-found-in-another-dataframe)
,But can't get my head around it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Add:

```
df['Event']=events['Event'].tolist()*2
```

To the end of the code.

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
        Date          Event        Place
0 2017-01-01    UniHolidays   university
1 2017-01-01  PublicHoliday  residential
2 2017-01-01  PublicHoliday     hospital
3 2017-01-02    UniHolidays   university
4 2017-01-02  PublicHoliday  residential
5 2017-01-02  PublicHoliday     hospital
```

**----------------------------------------**

**Solution 2:**

If want them to add in the right place do:

```
df=df.drop('Event',1)
df.insert(2,'Event',events['Event'].tolist()*2)
```

In the end of the code.

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
        Date        Place          Event
0 2017-01-01   university    UniHolidays
1 2017-01-01  residential  PublicHoliday
2 2017-01-01     hospital  PublicHoliday
3 2017-01-02   university    UniHolidays
4 2017-01-02  residential  PublicHoliday
5 2017-01-02     hospital  PublicHoliday
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------

**Solution 1** + **Solution 2**, will work,

But still best is to do singularly.

## Update:

Use:

```
df=df.drop('Event',1)
df.insert(2,'Event',events['Event'].tolist()*(len(df['Event'])/len(events['Event'].tolist())))
```

In the end of the code.

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
        Date        Place          Event
0 2017-01-01   university    UniHolidays
1 2017-01-01  residential  PublicHoliday
2 2017-01-01     hospital  PublicHoliday
3 2017-01-02   university    UniHolidays
4 2017-01-02  residential  PublicHoliday
5 2017-01-02     hospital  PublicHoliday
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Though it works for the sample data here, it doesn't work for my original data. I get the error "Length of values does not match length of index". Also, I do not understand how the Date range in "events" dataframe is used to identify the corresponding event in its respective place in df. what does df['Event']=events['Event'].tolist()*2 do?

Comment: @psangam Ok understand because i just multiply by two for this, so every time have to do more stuff, i'll edit quickly